# ffmpeg - Finding the right point to cut

Tags: ffmpeg

I cut videos using the command below, and I sometimes find that the resulting video has imperfections at the beginning (square artifacts in the image). If I advance the start time parameter value (`START_AT_SECONDS`) by a few seconds (usually 1..3s), the artifacts go away.

Is there a way to avoid the hit-and-miss, e.g. to know in advance that `START_AT_SECONDS=53` works but `START_AT_SECONDS=52` will give artifacts? Is there an option that means "START_AT_SECONDS=52, or later as needed to make a good cut"?

```
ffmpeg -ss START_AT_SECONDS -i "some_file_name.mp4" -t DURATION_SECONDS -c copy "new_name.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your ffmpeg command.

The `-c` option either needs a codec (e.g. `-c:v libx264`) if you want to encode the video or the special value "copy" if it shouldn't be re-encoded (`-c copy`).

Using `-ss` together with `-c copy` might not be accurate since ffmpeg is forced to only split on i-frames.
But starting on an i-frame should fix the problem with artifacts.

Comment: Apologies, I was already using "-c copy new_name.mp4". I have updated the question to reflect that.